# Add an attribute to the root element

Tags: xml, database, db2, xquery-sql

How can I add attribute to the root element of any XML documents which is a column in a table called book

```
this table contains bookid int
                    title  varchar(10)
                    Author varchar(10)
                    Order XML
```

order is an xml object in that table and it contains the folllowing

```
<buyOrder ordernum="10">
  <date>2010-12-3</date>
  <shippingdate>2010-12-5</shippingdate>
  <delivery>2010-12-12</delivery>
</buyOrder>
```

I want to add attribute called cost to the root element  ?

How can I do that please?

Comment: you mean you want to update what is already in the Order field with the exact same XML but with the new attribute?

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @Cost money = 10  

update book set
  [Order].modify('insert attribute cost {sql:variable("@Cost")} into (buyOrder[1])')
```